# How to tick the check boxes on page load using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<input type="hidden" id="amenities" value="@Model.Amenities" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {


    arr = new Array();

    var str = document.getElementById("amenities").value;

    arr = str.split(",");

    for(count =0;count<arr.length;count++)
    {
        $("input[type=checkbox][value=arr[count]]").prop("checked",true);​
    }
    </script>
```

In the model there is an attribute called "Amenities" of type string. It stores all the amenities like wifi, pool , park etc with delimiter (,). When I go to the edit page I want all those amenities to be checked which were earlier stored for that particular property.

Comment: Why don't you check it on the server when generating the page? I mean you have the data and you put it to a coma-separated string as hidden-field value to later check the checkboxes with javascript? What's the point?

Comment: I tried your thing. I changed it to a text-box and it is showing all the amenities. But I want to tick those checkboxes whose values are appearing in @Model.Amenities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do it on the server when you generate the view. All you need is:

```
public class MyModel
{
...
   public string[] Amenities { get; set; }
...
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.Checkbox("WiFi", @Model.Amenities.Contains("WiFi"))
@Html.Checkbox("Pool", @Model.Amenities.Contains("Pool"))
```

Of course it's just an example and in real life you'll probably have a list of possible Amenities and you iterate through to render checkboxes for each of them. Also instead of strings as values I would recommend and enum.

Comment: I didn't use the string array but still its working with the type 'string' without any need of script for splitting. Is there any specific reason for using array ?

Comment: Well, in general if you have to store several items of something then you usually store them in array, list, dictionary, hashtable etc. Strings are for text data. When you store your items in a comma separated string you'll have several implications: `String.Contains()` in not the same as `IEnumerable.Contains`. `"parking".Contains("park") == true`. Also searching the string for sub-string is a completely different operation from checking if a given item is in the list/array/hashtable or not.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var arr = $("#amenities").val().split(",");
       $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
          if($.inArray($(this).val(), arr) >= 0){
             $(this).attr("checked",true);
          }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah this is working great. Since I'm using MVC I will prefer using @html element. Though I have saved your code in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var arr = new Array();
        var str = $("#amenities").val();
        arr = str.split(",");
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(key,val){
            if(jQuery.inArray( $(this).val(), arr){
                $(this).prop("checked",true);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Check the above code.!!

One recommendation, Since you are using jQuery, GO with jQuery syntax.

Comment: Bro I tried your thing but it didn't work. Thanks for suggestion.